# Javascript doesnt work over $.ajax POST's result

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

edit: i included jquery files and functions in index.php, do i have to include them select.php?

i think now i will explain my problem clearly.

first, i want to send data to `select.php` via jquery `$.ajax`. there is nothing wrong in this part. but when i writing that returned data to my page javascripts doesnt work.

this is my code:

```
$('#sdata').change(function(){

    var id=$('#s_temsilci').val();


    $.ajax({
          type:"POST",          
          url: "select.php?do=delete_list",
          data: {id:id},
          success: function(result){

            $(".s_del").html(result);
                                    }   
        });

    });
```

select.php

```
    $id=$data->clean($_POST["id"]);
```

i have realy big form so i just write its part that requires jquery.

```
    <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload2').fileUploadStart()">start upload</a> |  
    <a href="javascript:$('#fileUpload2').fileUploadClearQueue()">Clean Queue</a>



    <input type="text" name="edit_d" class="datepicker" value="Date" />
```

these are doesnt work. if i use this same code in my index.php its working great.

Comment: did you try specifying the dataType attribute to either &lt;code&gt; json&lt;\\code&gt; or html

Comment: how are you returning result from select.php ?

Comment: `doesnt work` isn't a lot to go on ....what doesn't work..the ajax or the inline code functions in the form? Are any errors thrown in console. Provide as much detail as you can. Best guess is you haven't included the function definitions in the main page

Comment: no there is no error. i controlled it with firebug. 
@GBD i just use echo or normal html.

Comment: what you get if alert(result) ?

Comment: @charlietfl for example datepicker doesnt work, i include functions definitions in the main page but i dont include them in select.php.

Comment: do you have code to initialize datepicker after the form is loaded? The element needs to exist before datpicker code will work

Comment: With all chance, you aren't getting a 200/201 HTTP response message, thus `success` callback is not called at all. Inspect your Net panel in Firebug for any error, then fix it in your server side code.

Comment: @GBD i get what i wrote to select.php. when you click input it must be become datepicker but it doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

For datepicker to work after you load form with ajax you need to initialize it after it exists...within the success callback

```
 $.ajax({
      type:"POST",          
      url: "select.php?do=delete_list",
      data: {id:id},
      success: function(result){

        $(".s_del").html(result);
       /* datepicker element now exists*/
        $(".s_del .datepicker").datepicker({/* options*/})
       }   
    });

});
```

EDIT: Must also make sure that JQueryUI is loaded in main page as well as any other files that may be included in standalone page that does work